# Rosyln for static analysis

Tags: visual-studio-2015, roslyn

I have created a nuget package for live analysis using sdk template which works fine for live analysis. I saw only one assembly in the nugget package. This works.

Can I use the same assembly and the same rule to create a custom rule set file and do a analysis on build? I used the below ruleset code which throws error during build of the project. I have set the code analysis feature in the project properties.

My ultimate aim to use the custom rules I created as a ruleset in the  TFS check-in policy:

```
<RuleSet Name="Project WizBang Rules" ToolsVersion="1.1">
    <RuleHintPaths>
        <Path>C:\MyProjects\EYCodeRule\EYCodeRule\EYCodeRule\bin\Debug</Path>
    </RuleHintPaths>

    <Rules AnalyzerId="EYCodeRuleAnalyze" RuleNamespace="EYCodeRule">
        <Rule Id="3.4 NameSpace" Action="Warning" />
        <Rule Id="4.2 Class" Action="Warning" />
        <Rule Id="4.6 Field Naming" Action="Warning" />
    </Rules>
</RuleSet>
```

--Error message:

> Error  CA0053  CA0053 : Unable to load rule assembly 'c----->\eycoderule.dll': Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information.